# packaging AppJS all files into single executable file

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, appjs

I built an app with AppJS node modules . AppJS depend on many files . Is it possible to pack up all AppJS file into a single executable file? Like when user double click on `myapp.exe` and it launches as like a native app. Actually I want to hide my content files from users .

I am googling from last 2 days but I can't fiend any proper solution to do this . I just fiend some very old topic about it . I think,I can get an easy and updated solution for this .

Thank You !

Comment: are you tying to make a desktop application?

Comment: yes , I am a front end html5 developer so I just create my app using AppJS I think .

Comment: havnt used app js before sorry, if you run into to much trouble try electron instead. has really good documentation, good luck